# How to print a value which has been selected from a dropdown in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, ide, automated-tests

I am new to Selenium IDE, I don't know much in IDE, so just want to know how to print a value which has been selected from a Drop down.

```
<tr>
<td>select</td>
<td>id=xxxxx</td>
<td>label=yyyy</td>
</tr>
```

Above is my code which will select the value from a Drop down.

Now I want to print that value.

The problem is that when am trying to Print the value, all the values from the drop down gets printed.

Answer (score 0):

User storeSelectedValue command, below is examnple:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeSelectedValue</td>
    <td>selecttype</td>
    <td>value</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${value}</td>
    <td></td>
 </tr>
```